# Setup target location

Tags: installation

I need to find where the setup is installed by the user.. how ? please help me ..(i.e Need to find the target location selected by the user in vb.net)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If its the setup is on windows environment , go to start->programs

Locate the application executable name and place the cursor on it . It shows the location of the executable